# Multiple Criteria for If statement in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm attempting to modify an `applescript` that fires a growl notification when there is a new message in Outlook.  The original script is [here](http://www.eigenspace.org/2011/06/microsoft-outlook-growl-notifications/).

In my `if` statement, I am trying to say that if the folder is either Deleted Items, Junk E-mail or Sent Items, don't fire the notification.

Here is the statement:

```
if folder of theMsg is "Junk E-mail" or "Deleted Items" or "Sent Items" then
    set notify to false
else
    set notify to true
end if
```

It appear that applescript does not like the multiple is/or items I've added.  Is there a way to include the multiple criteria, or do I need to write a nested if/then?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The correct way to chain `if` conditions in AppleScript is to repeat the full conditional:

```
if folder of theMsg is "A" or folder of theMsg is "B" or folder of theMsg is "C" then
```

– there is no implicit repetition of the left hand argument. A more elegant way to do this is to compare your left hand argument to a list of items:

```
if folder of theMsg is in {"A", "B", "C"} then
```

which has the same effect (note this relies on the implicit coercion of *text* to *list*, which, depending on your `tell` context, may fail. In that case, explicitly coerce your left, i.e. `(folder of theMsg as list)`).

Answer (score 1):

When including multiple criteria in your conditional statements, you must rewrite the *entire conditional*. This can be extremely tedious at times, but that's just the way AppleScript works. Your expression would become the following:

```
if folder of theMsg is "Junk E-mail" or folder of theMsg is "Deleted Items" or folder of theMsg is "Sent Items" then
    set notify to false
else
    set notify to true
end if
```

There is a workaround, though. You can initialize all of your criteria into a list and see if your list contains a match:

```
set the criteria to {"A","B","C"}
if something is in the criteria then do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

Having come accross this post by Googling "applescript if multiple conditions" and didn't came accross the code snippet I was expecting here is what's I've done (just for informative purposes) :

You could also recursively scan multiple conditions. The following example is :
— Looking if the **sender** e-mail address **contains** (Arg 1.1) **something** (Arg 2.1.1 and 2.1.2) to immediately stop the script and "notify" => **true** (Arg 3.1).
— Looking if the **folder/mailbox** (Arg 1.2) **starts with "2012"** (Arg 2.2.1) but **is not folder 2012-A B or C** (Arg 2.2.2) if it doesn't start with 2012 or is contained in one of the 3 folders stop and do nothing => **false** (Arg 3.2).

```
if _mc({"\"" & theSender & " \" contains", "\"" & (name of theFolder) & "\""}, {{"\"@me.com\"", "\"Tim\""}, {"starts with \"2012\"", "is not in {\"2012-A\", \"2012-B\", \"2012-C\"}"}}, {true, false}) then
    return "NOTIFY "
else
    return "DO NOTHING "
end if
```

-- multiple conditions comparaison via a shell script

```
on _mc(_args, _crits, _r)
    set i to 0
    repeat with _arg in _args
        set i to i + 1
        repeat with _crit in (item i of _crits)
            if (item i of _r) as text is equal to (do shell script "osascript -e '" & (_arg & " " & _crit) & "'") then
                return (item i of _r)
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    return not (item i of _r)
end _mc
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW3

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
repeat with theMsg in theMessages
        set theFolder to name of theMsg's folder
        if theFolder is "Junk E-mail" or theFolder is "Deleted Items" or theFolder is "Sent Items" then
            set notify to false
        else
            set notify to true
        end if
    end repeat
```

Although the other two answers solve the multiple criteria correctly, they won't work unless you specify `name of theMsg's folder` or you will get

```
mail folder id 203 of application "Microsoft Outlook"
```